# Two Infinite Subsets, A and B, that are not Equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, solution-verification

Give an example of two infinite subsets *A* and *B* of the real numbers such that *A* $\ne$ *B* (*A* not equivalent *B*). Justify why they are not equivalent.

Here's what I did:

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subset of the real numbers,
let *A* = { $2x$ : $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ } and *B* = { $2x + 1$ : $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ }

*A* $\ne$ *B* because    $2x + 1$ $\ne$ $2x$  .

Is this an acceptable answer or is there a better example to use?

Comment: it's all right.

Comment: What do you mean by $=$?  Do you mean "the same set of real numbers"?  If so, then yes your example works.    Or does $=$ mean "in bijection with", which is what one would normally mean by "equivalent" for sets.  In which case your example is not correct.

Comment: @lulu "two **infinite** subsets."

Comment: @NoahSchweber   Yes, I just noticed that (and edited my comment accordingly).  But I still suspect the OP means "equivalent by bijection".

Comment: The sets are good examples, but the justification is not valid. While it is true that $2x + 1 \neq 2x$ for all $x$, there's no reason why the dummy variable $x$ in one set has to line up with the dummy variable $x$ in the other. Your logic doesn't account for $2x + 1 = 2y$ for some $y \in \Bbb{Z}$ (which it can't, but your logic should make it clear). Instead, pick a number (e.g. $5$) in $B$, and prove that $5 \neq 2x$ for any $x \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @user744868 That's a crucial point, which I missed (I saw what I was expecting to see).